# Is there a chart ID in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to add a series to a Highcharts chart after it has already rendered.

My Highcharts chart code starts off like this:

```
Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
        tooltip: {
...it keeps going
```

Is 'chart1' the chart ID. Like can I do this:

```
var chart = $("#chart1").highcharts();
chart.addSeries({
                data: logFunc(dataArr[3]);
            });
```

Also, is that logFunc function a valid way to input data if it returns a properly formatted array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Like can I do this:

Yes. Since 3.0.1 version you can get the chart object by `$("#chart1").highcharts();`

> is that logFunc function a valid way to input data if it returns a
>   properly formatted array?

Why not? Once you add new series it will redraw the chart with new series.See an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sy4jkqu4/1/)

Comment: Just a note: I didn’t have to redraw the chart I think it does it by default as part of addSeries